# Using CString in _T value

Tags: c++, mfc

I am making use of the EAGetMail Library but instead of hard coding the username and password, I am trying to pass two CString values as the credentials but it doesn't seem to like that.

```
CString username;
pObject->GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, username);

CString password;
pObject->GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT2, password);

IMailServerPtr oServer = NULL;
oServer.CreateInstance(__uuidof(EAGetMailObjLib::MailServer));

oServer->User = _T("myusername"); //THIS WORKS HARD CODED
```

Doesn't work:

```
oServer->User = username //Error, cannot be called with given argument list
```

I also tried:

```
oServer->User = _T(username); //L Username is undefined.
```

I guess I need to convert the CString somehow?

Tried the following:

```
//Get Email Credentials
CString username;
pObject->GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, username);

CString password;
pObject->GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT2, password);


_bstr_t usernamea(pObject->GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, username));
_bstr_t passworda(pObject->GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT2, password));
```

Comment: Hi. Please add enough code for us to verify and reproduce the problem, particularly the declaration of the variable `User`.

Comment: `_T` is only used for string literals. You need to say what the type of `User` is if you want an answer.

Comment: C++ _bstr_t EAGetMailObjLib::IMailServer::User

Comment: `_T("myusername");` <-- That code is undefined. *All* identifiers starting with underscore, followed by an uppercase letter, is *reserved for the implementation*. You are *Not* allowed to use such names in your own code.

Comment: @interjay "_T" is not a valid identifier in user code in the first place.

Comment: You can try `CComBSTR bstrUsername; bstrUsername = username.AllocSysString(); oServer->User = bstrUsername;` But have a look at the variable type for `oServer->User`. I assume `BSTR`.

Comment: So its not possible to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: it accepts: _bstr_t usernamea(pObject->GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, username)); but doesn't work so assuming it just reading garbage.

Comment: @Andrew: it is BSTR but I tried what you said and it doesn't accept it.

Comment: We don't know the expected  rules for your variable. In my projects when I use `CComBSTR` as I described it is fine. But I am not using your mail server product.

Comment: `CComBSTR` casts to `BSTR` so that should be fine. Have you ensured that the `CString` actually has a value? Have you ensured that `oServer` is not `null`? Can you be sure that the string needs conversion to another codepage or something? Look up the documentation for the object you are trying to populate. They must have examples.

Comment: @jes: The `_T` macro *is* provided by the implementation.

Comment: Please try to find a declaration of `IMailServer::User` and edit it into the question, so that we can be sure your successes aren't just lucky.

Comment: IMailServer::User is part of the EAGetMailObjLib. I have been running the test applicaiton for 6 hours non stop and it has been working flawlessly so far. I don't think its just luck. I will continue to monitor it.

Answer (score -1):

This worked.

```
//Get Email Credentials
CString username;
pObject->GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT1, username);
CString password;
pObject->GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT2, password);

CComBSTR bstrUsername; bstrUsername = username.AllocSysString();
_bstr_t usernamea(bstrUsername);
CComBSTR bstrPassword; bstrPassword = password.AllocSysString();
_bstr_t passworda(bstrPassword);

oServer->User = usernamea;
oServer->Password = passworda;
```

Comment: Why are you even getting your hands dirty with supporting ANSI encoding? It's a character encoding that doesn't work, and it's best to pretend that it never existed.

Comment: It does what I need it to do!

Comment: It's questionable whether *anyone* ever needs to allocate a `BSTR` only to immediately allocate yet another copy of the sane thing. This is code written by someone that doesn't understand the code they wrote.

Comment: @IInspectable. I'm trying, I'm learning so please try at the very least to be civil about it. We all have to start somewhere. Yes I have to allocate it twice for it to work and yes I do not know why, but it works so that is a start! Hopefully I can get to the bottom of that. I will be sure to update this if I find a better way of doing what I need it to do.

Comment: We still have no idea, which data typs are  oServer->User oServer->Password. Plz add this information

Comment: oServer->User oServer->Password are part of the EAGetMAil library (oServer.CreateInstance(__uuidof(EAGetMailObjLib::MailServer));. I'm not sure what else you want me to say?

Comment: Start by reading [ask]. Visitors to this site aren't going to be scanning through comments to figure out, what question is actually being asked. Just make sure to have *all* relevant information *in the question itself*. Taking the [tour] is a good start, too.

Answer (score -1):

Using C-style character pointers is the price we have to pay for making lower-level system calls to the OS.  Microsoft makes it more complicated because it has pairs of system calls, one for `char *` and `wchar_t` for the other. Typically you want to be consistent with one set or the other, so Microsoft provides a host of macros so that you can refer to the typical type of character `TCHAR` in the abstract.

`_T` is a Microsoft-specific macro that you should use only on string literals. It prepends an `L` to the literal when compiling a Unicode program (when `TCHAR` IS `wchar_t`) and does nothing for other programs (where `TCHAR` is `char`).

You've demonstrated that `IMailServer::User` will accept a string literal of type `TCHAR const *` but you store your data in a n MFC `CString`.

From the documentation of the MFC CString object:

> A CString object keeps character data in a CStringData object. CString accepts NULL-terminated C-style strings. CString tracks the string length for faster performance, but it also retains the NULL character in the stored character data to support conversion to LPCWSTR. CString includes the null terminator when it exports a C-style string.

You can convert a CString to a `TCHAR *` but for this you have to do it explicitly:

```
oServer->User = (LPCTSTR)username;
```

or the C++ way

```
oServer->User = static_cast<TCHAR const *>(username);
```

this will call [`CStringT<TCHAR>::operator PCXSTR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/csimplestringt-class?view=vs-2019#operator_pcxstr) to get the raw character pointer.

(Personally I'd use a `std::basic_string<TCHAR>` rather than a `CString` but that's just me).

Comment: Conversions from `CString` to `TCHAR const*` are implicit.

Comment: @IInspectable I haven't been able to find documentation for IMailServer, so I don't know what User takes; probably a `BSTR`. At any rate, in a chain of two implicit conversions you have to do one explicitly.

Comment: Correct, you only get one user-defined conversion. Still, *"You can convert a `CString` to a `TCHAR *` but you have to do it explicitly"* - while correct - is not what you are showing. And what you are showing happens implicitly.

Comment: @IInspectable We make this explicit so that the conversion to BSTR happens implicitly.

Comment: A `BSTR` is short for `wchar_t*`. If you need an explicit conversion, you have a bug. And if you are using an implicit conversion, you also have a bug. A `BSTR` is typed like a C-style string, but has different semantics. I'm sorry, this answer simply isn't useful.

Comment: @IInspectable I've no idea if it really wants a BSTR but assigning from the CString failed when the TCHAR* succeded. I bet OP compiled in ANSI or MBCS, so CString would be based on `char` not `wchar_t`.

Comment: If assigning from `CString` fails, but assigning from `TCHAR*` succeeds, then the issue is getting a *mutable* string, not a character encoding mismatch. Regardless, as written, the question is unanswerable. It needs to be fixed, or closed.

Comment: Well it worked perfectly for what I was trying to achieve!

Comment: @Spencer "*`_T` is a Microsoft-specific macro...*" - you are mixing up your macros. `TEXT()` is the Microsoft macro, and operates on `TCHAR` data. `_T()` is a C runtime macro, and operates on `_TCHAR` data. On Windows, they are usually interchangeable, as both `UNICODE` (Microsoft) and `_UNICODE` (C runtime) are defined (or not) together.